# i want to run an image publisher in ros2 using opencv but this error apppears i am working with ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, opencv, ros-humble

when i run this qrie@qrie-HP-Laptop-15-rb0xx:~/dev_ws$ ros2 run cv_basics img_publisher
i get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'
The C extension '/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' isn't present on the system. Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-without-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1